# Pandas using sepator ";" loses some values

Tags: python, pandas, separator

I'm using Python Pandas reading CSV file, calculating values and then creating a new CSV file of the just calculated values.

In my CSV files I have several columns. I have used `sep = ;` but then some of the cell values are missing (all of them are first in "General mode" in Excel but when creating a new CSV file they suddenly are missing and became in "Custom mode"). I have used also a `sep = ,`  and then I don't miss any values but the final CSV is not very easy to read, because all of the values are in the first and same column.

Any ideas? Thankful of any help!

There is a picture of what I got when using semicolon as a separator.[image]

Comment: Can you show an excerpt of your input csv?

Comment: Make sure the `deciamal`, `encoding`, `escapechar` and `quotechar` parameters are also set correctly: [pandas read_csv documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Thanks!! That did the thing :)